# How to convert string array of data object to array list of another data object in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have vehicle data object returning string array .I want to convert or cast to Arraylist  BuyingDo data object.I have ArrayList objectList

I am getting value like this

```
VehicleDo list[]=data.getList()
```

I am converting like this

```
objectList=(ArrayList<BuyingDo)list
```

but its not working can anybody tell how to do this

Comment: we need to see your BuyingDo class

Comment: I think the problem would be that these two classes would not be related. They must be an extension (extended) from one to the other for this to work. For example BuyingDo extends VehicleDo might be one way of the two. But you must put your complete code and the error/exception you get in order for someone to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit... well... unclear.

I think you mean either this:

```
List<VehicleDO> realList = Arrays.asList(list);
```

Or this:

```
List<BuyingDO> realList = new ArrayList<BuyingDO>(list.length);
for (VehicleDO vdo : list){
    realList.add((BuyingDO)vdo);
}
```

Assuming of course that VehicleDO can be cast to BuyingDO.

Something like that?